# Zurb Foundation 5 - making buttons responsive

Tags: button, sass, zurb-foundation

In Zurb **Foundation 5** - How can I responsively switch to the smaller button style when the browser is resized smaller or on a smaller screen?

**A similar question was asked and answered on StackOverFlow** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015849/zurb-foundation-how-do-you-make-buttons-smaller-on-resize-to-a-smaller-screen) **but that correct solution does not work with Foundation 5, guessing it only works in Foundation 4.**

The buttons currently look like this ($button-lrg) when resized to a smaller screen:
[image]

But I want the buttons to look more like this ($button-sml) when resized to a smaller screen:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

I came up with a sass/scss mixin based off of the correct answer from the similar question link above. Just add the following mixin to your "app.scss" file:

```
@media #{$small-up} { 
    .responsive-button {
        @include button($button-sml, $primary-color, 0px, false, false, false); 
    }
}

@media #{$medium-up} {
    .responsive-button {
        @include button($button-lrg, $primary-color, 0px, false, false, false); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with [visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html):

```
<div class="show-for-medium-up">
    <a href="#" class="button large alert">Button 1 </a>
    <a href="#" class="button large ">Button 2</a>
</div>
<div class="hide-for-medium-up">
    <a href="#" class="button tiny  alert">Button 1 </a>
    <a href="#" class="button tiny ">Button 2</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltamvrc7/

*Foundation devs used this technique on their site.*

Comment: Great solution JAre! Thank you! I came up with a mixin solution based off of the similar previous StackOverFlow question link in my question, I'll add it as a solution in my question.